# BackPressed issue in PRISM UniversalApp

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, prism

I'm working on an UniversalApp using the Library Prism.
My App.cs inherit MvvmAppBase so it will handle automatically the back pressed event and this is the problem because I have some cases in my app when the user press on back button it will show him a Message Box for example.

I tried to handle the event back press on my App.cs but the problem is still persist, the page go back in all cases. I want to block the page and not GoBack.

I have found a solution that say to implement a new interface INavigateBackwards but I don't have an idea what should I add on this new interface.

I think many developers who work with prism  already faced the same problem so can anyone help me for this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Think it has been mentioned and has a fix in the questions section of PRISM: http://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/discussions/570033#post1341559

Comment: It's one of the things we plan to fix in Prism 6.